# Android: How to implement custom Clock View as shown in the Honor clock app. See attachment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[image: Custom View]

I recently bought Huawei Honor 6x and the clock application in the system, is very polished and I am really curious as to how to create such a custom View for the clock. The current second pointer circle and the curved wave that moves with it.

Some helpful pointers will be really helpful. The lines and the curve that moves with the seconds.

I know it has to be a custom view, but still can't figure out the way.